# How to delete lines if few rows have met some condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file look like:

```
dates, names, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7 
1-3-2017,Bob,somedata,somedata,somedata,somedata,somedata
1-1-2018,Bob,-,-,-,-,-
1-1-2017,Bob,somedata,somedata,somedata,somedata,somedata
```

I want to delete rows if these rows have `-` in column3, column4, column5, column6 and column7 using pandas.

After removal of the unnecessary information, file will look like this

```
dates, names, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7 
1-1-2017,Bob,somedata,somedata,somedata,somedata,somedata
1-3-2017,Bob,somedata,somedata,somedata,somedata,somedata
```

Can't understand how to do it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straightforward way is to convert `-` to `np.nan`, then use `df.dropna`.

```
import numpy as np

df = df.replace('-', np.nan).dropna(subset=['column'+str(i) for i in range(3, 8)])

#       dates names   column3   column4   column5   column6   column7
# 0  1-3-2017   Bob  somedata  somedata  somedata  somedata  somedata
# 2  1-1-2017   Bob  somedata  somedata  somedata  somedata  somedata
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
filtered = data[(data.column3 != "-") & (data.column4 != "-") & (data.column5 != "-") & (data.column6 != "-") & (data.column7 != "-")]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the cells might contain only '-', try

```
new_df = df[~(df.iloc[:, 2:] == '-').any(1)]
```

If they might contain '-' with some other characters,

```
new_df = df[~df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('-').any(), axis = 1)]
```

Either way you get

```
    dates.      names   column3     column4     column5     column6     column7
0   1-3-2017    Bob     somedata    somedata    somedata    somedata    somedata
2   1-1-2017    Bob     somedata    somedata    somedata    somedata    somedata
```